# Crear un nuevo array con atributos específicos (Otro Array y que no se repitan atributos)

Tags: javascript, array, angular, typescript

Estoy tratando de crear un nuevo Array en un proyecto de Angular en base a los atributos del antiguo Array (Y un atributo tiene que ser un Array), Utilice la función `map` pero el resultado no es el deseado.

**this.categories2** Tiene una serie de atributos y lo transformo de la siguiente manera:

```
const list = this.categories2.map(chanel => ({
    name: chanel.info.image.link,
    category: chanel.info.category
}));
console.log(list);
```

**Resultado:**

```
[
  {"name": "https://www.eltiempo.com", "category": "Colombia"},
  {"name": "https://www.eltiempo.com", "category": "Internacional"},
  {"name": "https://www.eltiempo.com", "category": "Latinoamérica"},
  {"name": "https://www.eltiempo.com", "category": "EEUU y Canadá"},
  {"name": "https://www.eltiempo.com", "category": "Asia"},
  {"name": "https://www.portafolio.co", "category": "Economía"},
  {"name": "https://www.portafolio.co", "category": "Negocios"},
  {"name": "https://www.portafolio.co", "category": "Internacional"},
  {"name": "https://www.portafolio.co", "category": "Innovación"},
  {"name": "https://www.portafolio.co", "category": "Tendencias"}
]
```

Como se puede evidenciar el atributo `name` se repite varias veces por cada `category` pero me gustaría lograr lo siguiente:

```
[
  {
    "name": "https://www.eltiempo.com",
    "category": ["Colombia", "Internacional", "Latinoamérica", "EEUU y Canadá", "Asia"]
  },
  {
    "name": "https://www.portafolio.co",
    "category": ["Economía", "Negocios", "Internacional", "Innovación", "Tendencias"]
  }
]
```

Hay alguna forma de lograr esto? Estuve intentando con la función `map` pero no veo una forma optima de lograr transformar el Array de esa manera.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const arreglo = [
  {"name": "https://www.eltiempo.com", "category": "Colombia"},
  {"name": "https://www.eltiempo.com", "category": "Internacional"},
  {"name": "https://www.eltiempo.com", "category": "Latinoamérica"},
  {"name": "https://www.eltiempo.com", "category": "EEUU y Canadá"},
  {"name": "https://www.eltiempo.com", "category": "Asia"},
  {"name": "https://www.portafolio.co", "category": "Economía"},
  {"name": "https://www.portafolio.co", "category": "Negocios"},
  {"name": "https://www.portafolio.co", "category": "Internacional"},
  {"name": "https://www.portafolio.co", "category": "Innovación"},
  {"name": "https://www.portafolio.co", "category": "Tendencias"}
];

// extraer diferentes valores de name
let names = [];

arreglo.forEach(o =>{
  if(!names.includes(o.name)) names.push(o.name);
});




let resultado = [];

// recorrer arreglo de names y agrupar las categories
names.forEach(n => {

  let categories = [];
  
  // insertar en categories las categorias que coincidan con name
  arreglo.forEach( o => {
    if(o.name == n) categories.push(o.category);
  });
  
  // insertar un nuevo objeto en resultado que contiene el name
  // y el arreglo de categorias
  resultado.push({
   name : n,
   categories : categories
  });

});

console.log(resultado);
```